Azure API Manager - SOAP pass-through - Base URL and WSDL - Spring Boot
I am trying to make a successful call
from my "Spring Boot Application"
to a SOAP API on the "Azure API Manager".
I have defined a WSDL

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                 xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                 xmlns:tns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"
                 name="PutMessage"
                 targetNamespace="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
          <xs:element name="PutMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="PutMessageRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="PutMessageResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PutMessageResult" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
      </types>
      <message name="PutMessage">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:PutMessage"/>
      </message>
      <message name="PutMessageSoapRequest">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:PutMessageRequest"/>
      </message>
      <message name="PutMessageResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:PutMessageResponse"/>
      </message>
      <portType name="PutMessageSoapType">
        <operation name="PutMessage">
          <documentation>Returns the feedback by AzureServicebus when a message is pasted into it.</documentation>
          <input message="tns:PutMessageSoapRequest"/>
          <output message="tns:PutMessageResponse"/>
        </operation>
      </portType>
      <binding name="PutMessageSoapBinding" type="tns:PutMessageSoapType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="PutMessage">
          <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </output>
        </operation>
      </binding>
      <binding name="PutMessageSoapBinding12" type="tns:PutMessageSoapType">
        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="PutMessage">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
          <input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
          </output>
        </operation>
      </binding>
      <service name="PutMessage">
        <documentation>The Web Service, to interact with azure service bus.</documentation>
        <port name="PutMessageSoap" binding="tns:PutMessageSoapBinding">
          <soap:address location="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso"/>
        </port>
        <port name="PutMessageSoap12" binding="tns:PutMessageSoapBinding12">
          <soap12:address location="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso"/>
        </port>
      </service>
    </definitions>

And uploaded the WSDL to the Azure API Manager.


Spring Boot SOAP CLient
Further

I have generated WebServiceFactory inheriting from jakarta.xml.ws.Service
and WebService "PutMessageSoapType" annotated with @WebService

So that I am now set to call the SOAP API.

    PutMessage_Service putMessageService = new PutMessage_Service();
    PutMessageSoapType myWebService = putMessageService.getPutMessageSoap();

    PutMessageRequest putMessageRequest = new PutMessageRequest();
    putMessageRequest.setMessage("");
    myWebService.putMessage(putMessageRequest);


Question:
what I fail to recognize is
how to point the Spring Boot SOAP Client
to the Base URL https://alfdevapi5-example-apim.azure-api.net/suffix1 of the Azure API Manager API?

Can you show a screenshot of the Operations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses?tabs=azure-portal#add-an-operation-to-the-test-api

Sure, added. But which role does it play for my question?

/?soapAction=PutMessage - this looks like a query and not a part of the URL path. Although https://alfdevapi5-example-apim.azure-api.net/suffix1 is your base URL, the Frontend URL value of the operation adds another section to this path, e.g. if you put /suffix2 there then the whole URL for this operation would become https://alfdevapi5-example-apim.azure-api.net/suffix1/suffix2 - queries are not supposed to be used in the Frontend URL values, to my knowledge.

But how to use the "Base URL" in the Spring Boot code?
Cant find a way to provide "Base URL" to the SOAP API call.
